# How to verify digital signature of .exe/.dll file in Windows programmatically

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, pki, code-signing-certificate

I have some Windows dlls/.exes built as part of a build process and they are signed with our corporate code-signing certificate using Windows `signtool`.
I have a Java application that needs to verify the following:

1. Whether a given .exe/.dll file has a digital signature or not
2. Whether the signature can be verified to a known root certs (i.e. basically to check whether it is not signed with a self-signed certificate)

I came across doing this from .NET applications, but nothing from Java side. I am wondering how to do this programmatically from a Java application.

Comment: Not super helpful, but you can start by following this example: https://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleSMIMEverify.html

Comment: It is good. But doesn't cover how to extract signature from the .exe

Comment: Our SecureBlackbox (Java edition) includes TElAuthenticodeVerifier class, which checks digital signatures of Windows EXE and DLL files.